# Boost Smart pointers and static initialization order fiasco

Tags: c++, boost

I use boost smart pointers extensively throughout my code.

I have seen some strange core dumps recently and one area of concern is the possibility of the static initialization order fiasco and boost smart pointers.

Is there an issue having a boost::shared_ptr as a static object. 
I have checked the boost code and I don't see any static data in the shared_ptr that would be a cause of concern.

An example of the pattern is as follows:

```
class ObjectFactory {
public:
    static boost::shared_ptr<ObjectInterface> createObject();
private:
    static boost::shared_ptr<ObjectInterface> m_object;
};
```

The factory hides the implementation actually returned to the user. It also ensures only a single instance of the implementation is created and stores it in m_object. 
m_object will then be destroyed once main finishes i.e. static data is cleaned up.

I could also use the singletone pattern here but again the static instance variable would be bound to a static boost shared_ptr.

If possible I would like confirmation that there is no issue with above pattern.

Thank you.
Dave.

Comment: AFAIK there's no initialization order fiasco for static entities in the same translation unit

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for a definitive answer. If you call `createObject()` before `main` begins then that's a cause for concern. Using a function-local static instead of a static member variable might be a good alternative, as it will be created as needed.

Comment: Also, a general note about statics and initialization: Newer versions of e.g. gcc adds an invisible compiler-generated mutex around function-local statics to avoid the possibility of e.g. two threads running the same singleton's destructor. See e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2660.htm